# ES6 Modules Namespace Collision

Tags: javascript

The point of the code below was to see if I can print an element in its original state and its modified state, it seems as if such a thing is not possible without a dynamic import function.
I assume this happens because the static imports are evaluated during load-time but if there is a hacky way to get around that I'm all ears.

**module01.js**

```js
const element = document.createElement('div');

element.innerText = 'Module1';

export { element };
```

**module02.js**

```js
import { element } from './module1.js';

element.innerText = 'Module2';

export { element as newElem }
```

**script.js**

```js
import { element } from './modules/module1.js'
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(element);

import { newElem } from './modules/module2.js';
div.appendChild(newElem);

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

*DOM shows "Module2" if both modules are imported and "Module1" if only the first one is.*

Comment: A given element can only be in the DOM once.

Comment: The "element" from module01 is only created once. Then module02 re-uses the same element; it does *not* create a separate element. So the element from module01 has its text content changed to "Module2". There is a `cloneNode` method, though, if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> see if I can print an element in its original state and its modified state

No, you can't, and this has nothing to do with modules. It's the same as putting all the code in a single file:

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerText = 'Module1';

element.innerText = 'Module2';
const newElem = element;

const div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(element);
div.appendChild(newElem);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

There is only a single `element` object, shared between the modules and referenced from multiple variables. This one object cannot have multiple states at the same time, and it can only exist once in the DOM. `appendChild` does not create a copy.

If you want to see two elements, you'll need to create a separate `<div>` instead of sharing it.

If you just want to *print* the temporary state of the object in *module01.js* before it gets modified in *module02.js*, add `console.log(element.outerHTML)`.